# How to select my second radio button in javascript without using id?

Tags: javascript, input, radio-button, selector

Hee, I'm working on something but can and dont want to change the HTML. Adding an ID button is not possible. I want to select the second radio input.

This is the html:

```html
  <fieldset>
        <legend>I want to sign up:</legend>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="submit-for" value="project">
            <span>For project</span>
        </label>
        <label>
           <input type="radio" name="submit-for" value="stage">
           <span>As intern</span>
       </label>
  </fieldset>
```

This are the ways i tried selecting it in javascript but it didnt work:

```js
   document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:nth-of-type(2)').onclick = function () {
       document.getElementById("project").style.display = 'none';
       document.getElementById("stage").style.display = 'block';
   };
```

and

```js
   document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:nth-child(2)').onclick = function () {
       document.getElementById("project").style.display = 'none';
       document.getElementById("stage").style.display = 'block';
   };
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('fieldset input[type:radio]').item(1)` (be sure to check if it exists, as it could be `undefined` if there are no two elements)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you really want to select "the second" radio button, or do you want to select "the radio button with value 'stage'"? The second option sounds more extensible.

```
document.querySelector('input[type="radio"][value="stage"]')
```

EDIT: Also, upvoted your question for not resorting to ID usage. Always good practice, whether or not you're forced into it.

Comment: I <3 YOU!!! thanks so much i was stuck on this for hours trying to figure out how to part of my form disappear by selecting a radio button. Finally figured it out. Sending positive energy to you! Didnt know you could select by value.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.querySelectorAll('fieldset input[type="radio"]')[1]=function () {
  document.getElementById("project").style.display = 'none';
         document.getElementById("stage").style.display = 'block';
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.getElementByName` and select the second of the set:

```
document.getElementsByName("submit-for")[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

The user @somethinghere was close and the OP chose an answer that did not apply to the title of the question so for those who *are* looking for the answer to the title of the question here you go:

```
var r = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
if (r.item.length > 0) {console.log(r.item(1));
```